# Why iTunes doesn't detect my app distributed with wireless distribution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, distribution, wireless

I developed a test App that I distribute to my iPhone with wireless distribution and everything works. There is only one problem sigh :(, I try to synchronize my iPhone with iTunes but it doesn't see my app. Why?
Thanks,
Alleria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the provisioning profile to iTunes?  See [here](http://www.oogtech.org/content/tag/provisioning-profile/) for some great instructions in setting up ad-hoc distributions via iTunes.